# PHP Mailer ensure authenticity

Tags: php, phpmailer

I was just introduced to PHP mailer , it is great .U can attach things and do all sorts of stuff.WOW, my question is that since it gives us the freedom of sending the mail by any name or email id , so how does one ensure that no one else is using their email to send email to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways. Look up SPF (detects unauthorised source mail servers), DKIM (guarantees you are who you say you are and that your message has not been altered in transit), DMARC (lets you know about failures of the others), S/MIME (signs content cryptographically to prove sender is authentic). PHPMailer supports all of those. To go further you could look into S/MIME encryption, or PGP/GPG for a similar technology, but PHPMailer does not support them as yet. Many services add additional protection - for example gmail does not let you use arbitrary from addresses.